# Can I say Jesus' arrival was through conception of the Holy Spirit?

Tags: life-of-jesus

I am writing an essay. I wrote an sentence like this, Jesus' arrival was prophesied and, moreover, was through the conception of the Holy Spirit. I am not sure whether it makes sense doctrinal sense according to Protestantism to say Jesus' arrival was through conception. Could anyone tell me?

Comment: Hi Lily, the question is off topic and too broad to be answered here. I recommend that you change the penultimate sentence to "I am not sure whether it makes _doctrinal_ sense _according to (insert denomination of interest here)_ to say Jesus' arrival was through conception. Could anyone tell me?"

Comment: @Flimzy She is clearly not asking if it makes _grammatical_ sense.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Could you explain further why you are not sure if it makes sense to use this wording?

Comment: I don't know if this helps (either with resolving your question or helping you refine it), but translations of the Apostles' Creed variously say he was "conceived by the Holy Spirit" or simply "conceived by the Holy Spirit" and the Gospel of Matthew says he was "conceived from the Holy Spirit."

Comment: Yes, I was wondering maybe the sentence beginning with "Jesus" rather than "Jesus' arrival" is correct. But I don't want to change the subject, and so I asked this question. And I thought someone knows more than me could correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you mean, in the title of your question, "conception *of* the Holy Spirit" or "Conception *by* the Holy Spirit?" In English, all prepositions are not equivalent, but usage has changed over the centuries.

Comment: No, I am not sure whether the subject of the sentence "Jesus' arrival" matches well with "through the conception."

Answer (score 2):

**Matthew 1:18** New American Standard Bible (NASB)

**Conception and Birth of Jesus**

18 Now the birth of Jesus Christ was as follows: when His mother Mary had been betrothed to Joseph, before they came together she was found to be with child by the Holy Spirit.

As for a Catholic perspective, we have no problem declaring that Jesus was conceived by the power of the Holy Spirit. In the [Apostles' Creed](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles%27_Creed) we profess this very fact:

"I believe in Jesus Christ, his only Son, our Lord. He was conceived by the power of the Holy Spirit and born of the Virgin Mary."

The Church of England, the United Methodist Church and the Ecumenical version of the English Language Liturgical Consultation all share similar wording in their [professions of faith.](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles%27_Creed)